# CSS left triangle after square link

Tags: html, css

Trying to add a triangle to the end of a link thats responsive. I can do it when the link is fixed however when longer words are used it breaks. Thanks

Code is:

```
<a href="" class="blue-btn">View this project</a>
<br><br><br>
<a href="" class="blue-btn">View this longer project</a>

a.blue-btn {
  padding: 10px 22px;;
  background-color: blue;
  color:white;
  position:relative;
}
a.blue-btn:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0;
left: 154px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-width: 42px 42px 0 0px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Fiddle is: 
https://jsfiddle.net/0047g8vv/4/

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441122/shape-with-a-slanted-side-responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "left" property and add a negative "right" property with the same value as the border width :

```
a.blue-btn {
  padding: 10px 22px;;
  background-color: blue;
  color:white;
  position:relative;
}
a.blue-btn:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: -42px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-width: 42px 42px 0 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/0047g8vv/3/

Comment: This works however it's forcing the hover not to change on hover: I've updated the fiddle to include the hover state: https://jsfiddle.net/0047g8vv/4/

Comment: Just change the border-top-color on hover accordingly: https://jsfiddle.net/03cb35cp/

Answer (score 0):

```
a.blue-btn:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #007bff;
    right:-10px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the position properties, doesn't make sense in your case to specify both left and right - because you want it to respond to width changes.

```
a.blue-btn:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: -42px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-width: 42px 42px 0 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you were setting the position using `left`, You want the triangle positioned the same distance to `right` no matter the size of the element. I've updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0047g8vv/)

I've set `right: -38px` and also reduced the size of the triangles so they fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left: 100%` to do it responsive like this:

```css
a.blue-btn {
  padding: 10px 22px;;
  background-color: blue;
  color:white;
  position:relative;
}
a.blue-btn:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-width: 39px 42px 0 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="blue-btn">View this project</a>
<br><br><br>
<a href="" class="blue-btn">View this longer project</a>
<br><br><br>
<a href="" class="blue-btn">View this longer longer longer longer longer project</a>
```

This way you ensure that the arrow is always in the right place, regardless of the width of the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

[Here you go](https://jsfiddle.net/v05udjxh/), just add a minus right on there.

```
a.blue-btn:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -0.4px;
    right: -40px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-width: 37.9px 42px 0 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the previous answers, I would specify the `display` of the `a` as `inline-block` and loose the `padding-top` and `-bottom` to ensure the correct height:

```css
a.blue-btn {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  height: 42px; // ensures the correct height - same value as in the :after
  line-height: 42px; // center the text vertically
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
a.blue-btn:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: -42px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 42px 42px 0 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<br><a href="" class="blue-btn">View this project</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<a href="" class="blue-btn">View this longer project</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.blue-btn {
  padding: 10px 22px;;
  background-color: red;
  color:white;
  position:relative;
}
a.blue-btn:after {
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    top: 27px;
    right: 0;
    left: 59px;
    border-width: 37px 37px 0 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Solve your problem?

If you change the padding you to change the left and top proporcinalmente also