# slanting axe using css

Tags: html, css

I want to do a "split" on my website using a "slanting" axe. I try to use it with basic HTML , CSS with `transform` and `rotate` but I can't have the correct result. I try to get something looking like this : 
[image]

But the rotate attribute isn't the best for this

Does another CSS attribut can give me the expected result? Or do you have any good tuto ? Thank.

My current uneffective :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>slanting axe</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="test" class="col-lg-12">
    <div id="red" class="col-lg-6">
    </div>
    <div id="blue" class="col-lg-6">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

## CSS

```
#test{
height:500px;
}

#red{
height:500px;
background-color:red;
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

#blue{
height:500px;
background-color:blue;
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

Comment: You could have a look at the various methods described in this thread to produce a slanted side and position appropriately - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441122/shape-with-a-slanted-side-responsive

Comment: Didn't found this one with search tool. Ty. Note duplicate.