# Want to create a div with just one corner raised a little bit up with css / html

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to create a div with its right corner raised a little bit up. I have tried using it with borders but in vein. Please take a look at the picture and any suggestions will be appreciated :)

[image]

I have used css3 skew but it didn't work for me as I wanted

Comment: Did you google anything?

Comment: I have checked the Skewed Borders post but its affecting on every border... I just want to lift the upper right corner ... Which seems not to be the answer in Skewed Borders post

Comment: @Martijn Pieters please undelete my answer... It was mistakenly posted on two questions... I have deleted it on the wrong question and want it back to this post.

Comment: @Omer, see **Method 2 - Gradient Background** in Harry's Answer in the link [Shape with a slanted side (Responsive)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441122/shape-with-a-slanted-side-responsive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, have found a way to achieve this with border and not with skew.

Here is my code...

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  margin: 50px 0 0;
}
.box:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 30px transparent solid;
  border-right: 300px green solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

But now another issue. The code above is useful for anyone who wants to make divs with fixed widths. What if I want to use this div as 100% of width but I cannot add % in the border in my css.

Any suggestions will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this?

I used Three `divs`. A parent `div`, and two `divs` inside the parent `div`:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin:50px;
    min-width:400px;
    background:white;
}
.container{
    width: 300px;
}
.top{
    with: 100%;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 50px solid red;
    border-left: 300px solid transparent;
}
.main {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/53FrA/439/)**

Comment: Yes this is what I have already done... But it is fixed in width. Can we make it flexible?