# CSS only 2 striped background (skewed)

Tags: css

Been digging into a way to make a two striped background with CSS only. Trying to accomplish this:

[image]

Comment: You can do it using angled linear gradients (like the second snippet in **question** here (angle needs to be changed) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441122/shape-with-a-slanted-side-responsive). I am sure this is a dupe but not able to find the perfect one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(65deg, white 50%, #5C8F09 50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, I'll accept as soon as it let's me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [gradient background](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) to accomplish this effect.

I like to use this [background generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), online to play around.

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0bqf35h7/).

You will need to tweak the color stops.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ff3232+0,ff3030+48,ffffff+48 */
background: #ff3232; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #ff3232 0%, #ff3030 48%, #ffffff 48%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #ff3232 0%,#ff3030 48%,#ffffff 48%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff3232 0%,#ff3030 48%,#ffffff 48%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3232', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```