# Responsive header with angle one side

Tags: html, css

When browser get resized absolutely positioned after pseudo-element overflows and causes problems. I am looking for a way to fix this. Just resize the browser until you reach header text.

[image: wide header test text]

Here is a demo of the problem: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grKNoJ

```
.section {
  font-family: 'Quantico';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: white;
  border-top: solid 1px black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 28px;
}

.section-title {
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  position: relative;
}
.section-title:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #000;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  -ms-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
}
```

Comment: Related (or possible duplicate of) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441122/shape-with-a-slanted-side-responsive

Comment: @Harry its related but I think its not dupe since this deals with text

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by adding `text-overflow: ellipsis;` and `white-space: nowrap;` to `.section-title`.

You could also set a `max-width` to that element, and set it to different values according to your media queries, and have it serve your needs on different devices.

Here is the updated result: http://codepen.io/johnnykb/pen/mPKZLg

Comment: but browser still scrolls horizontally.

Comment: @GorillaApe check out the new code. Adding `overflow: hidden;` to `.section` will do the trick.