# Html transform property

Tags: html, css

How to set text and background on this div straight? The transform property is making it curved.

```css
#paralelogram {
  margin-left: 190px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  transform: skew(-30deg);
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/80/animals/8/');
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#cena {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 volks">
  <div id="paralelogram">
    <p id="cena">136,380 Kn</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I took the liberty of turning your source into a stacksnippet. But I can't see what you mean by curved. Can you explain?

Comment: Delete the `transform: skew(-30deg);`? Or are you not allowed to touch the source code?

Comment: I assume the OP wants the `#paralelogram` container to be skewed, but not the text or the background image.

Comment: Yes @showdev, container should be skewed but not image and text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative idea is to use [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to mask out the parallelogram shape rather than `transform:skew`. One current caveat is limited [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

My example is based on [Harry's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry) [answer to "Shape with a slanted side (responsive)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441122/shape-with-a-slanted-side-responsive#answer-30441123):

```css
#parallelogram {
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  background-color: grey;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/g/240/80/);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 100% 0%, 80% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 100% 0%, 80% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="parallelogram">136,380 Kn</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a pseudo for the image and then reverse the skew on it and the `p` with `transform: skew(30deg);`

```css
#paralelogram {
  margin-left: 190px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  transform: skew(-30deg);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: gray;
}
#paralelogram:before {
  content: '';
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: -20px;
  transform: skew(30deg);
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/240/80/animals/8/');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
}
#cena {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  transform: skew(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 volks">
  <div id="paralelogram">
    <p id="cena">136,380 Kn</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, but looks like the image doesn't reach the edges of the skewed container.