# CSS diagonal div background

Tags: html, css, diagonal

For a website I'm developing I need to include some diagonal shaped borders to a `div`. These are the main examples which I need to recreate.

[double diagonal top border, triangle shaped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d44D3.png)

Now been scouting the web on how to achieve this, and my first thought as well would be by using `::before`. However I can't get it to work without it being positioned absolute which messes up the entire page.

This is my code I have tried to achieve something like this:

```css
.slider-container{
  background-color: $blue;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  .col-md-3{
    img{
      padding: 40px;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 400px;
      margin: auto;
    }
  }
  &::before {
    background: red;
    bottom: 100%;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
    width: 150%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="slider">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row slider-container">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>imgae 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>imgae 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>imgae 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>imgae 4</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Note: it won't work in here but this is the result I get [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2pm8.png)

Comment: Can you post html and css of what you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shape with a slanted side (responsive)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441122/shape-with-a-slanted-side-responsive)

Comment: Try implementing transform skew property eg `transform: skew(0deg,5deg);`

Comment: i'll update the question with my code i have now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With just css and a bit tweaking based on your divs size you could create something like this:

```css
.myclass {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: linear-gradient(45deg, black 0%, black 26%, transparent 26%), linear-gradient(-45deg, black 0%, black 27%, transparent 27%)
}

.myclass2 {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: linear-gradient(-45deg, blue 0%, blue 27%, transparent 27%), linear-gradient(45deg, blue 0%, blue 26%, red 26%)
}
```

```html
With transparency:
<div class="myclass">My content here</div>
<br/>
Not as easy with transparent:
<div class="myclass2">My content here</div>
```

Edit: Just tested this in chrome, you might need special linear-gradients for older/other browsers.

Comment: Nevermind, fiddled around with the height and some other properties and it is what i'm looking for thanks!

Comment: I suggest using "to bottom left" and "to bottom right" for the linear gradients instead of an angle. This way it will adjust the diagonality(?) to the height of the container.

Answer (score 5):

The most simple way to achieve this would probably be to use a background image, though the effect may prove to be inconsistent on smaller devices. For this reason, you may want to consider using a hard-stop gradient.

```css
.grad {
  background: lightblue; /* For browsers that don't support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(170deg, white 0%, white, 15%, lightblue 15%, lightblue 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(170deg, white 0%, white, 15%, lightblue 15%, lightblue 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(170deg, white 0%, white, 15%, lightblue 15%, lightblue 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(170deg, white 0%, white, 15%, lightblue 15%, lightblue 100%);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grad">
  <h1>Hard-stop gradient</h1>
  <p>Using this type of gradient, you can create an angled background without using a background image.</p>
</div>
```

Using this, you can create a gradient from 0% to 15% that is white on both ends, followed by a gradient from 15% to 100% that's fully black. This completely removes the fading effect, giving you your angled background. It's probably the most efficient way as well since it only requires one line of CSS.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `clip-path`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  color: #ffffff;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100vw;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: red;
}

.bg {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  background-color: blue;
  clip-path: polygon(80% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```css
div {
  background: yellow;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

div::before {
  background: red;
  bottom: 100%;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
  width: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: indeed something like this, however when this div follows another it will not be cut off on the top like your example because its outside of the viewport

Answer (score 1):

For me, the `linear-gradient` is not smooth ...
I would suggest either `clip-path` or `svg`:

```
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;      
}

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <polygon points="100 0 100 10 0 10" fill="white" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.arrow-right {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 60px solid green;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;

  border-left: 60px solid green;
}
```

Comment: i've seen this anwser on a similar question however it only seems to focus on the diagonal side div and not the div which has these like triangles on both side. Also i can't seem to figure it out completely

Comment: gives me a weird shape with downshaped border on the left side of my div?