# Create a non rectangular Bulma hero

Tags: css, bulma

I  would like to use the Bulma CSS framework and be able to create non rectangular hero sections, like this one :

[image: non-rectangular-header]

Of course, any solution allowing me to use Bulma color gradients ("is-bold" class) would be even best. But just this slight slope with a plain hero background color would still be very useful.

Any ideas on the CSS needed to achieve this with a Bulma Hero section ?

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441122/shape-with-a-slanted-side-responsive

Comment: That question doesn't mention the Bulma CSS framework AFAIK