# HTML/CSS Formatting - Slash on "news ticker"

Tags: html, css

This doesn't have to do anything relating to make it a ticker related component, I've already done that already. I just wanted to polish the way it looked by adding a slash "/" contrast between the two colors.  I want to avoid adding a separate `div` component just for the slash. I've added a picture of the example here (sorry to the colorblind people, it's probably difficult to tell):

[image: Example Picture]

---

tl;dr Basically, how do I add that slash (circled in red) without using a `div` box reserved for the slash?

Here's my current code:

```css
.tickerv-wrap {
  background: #eee;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 19px;
  /* container that only displays this height... correlate with tickerv-wrap ul li line-height, was 1px smaller than tickerv-wrap ul li line-height */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Hide scrollbars */
  padding: 1px;
  /* watch for this as well... best to put as line-height - height */
}


/* TICKER ANIMATION */

@keyframes tickerv {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  /* Quite literally -ve height of wrapper */
  25% {
    margin-top: -19px;
  }
  /* 1 X tickerv-wrap height */
  50% {
    margin-top: -38px;
  }
  /* 2 X tickerv-wrap height px */
  75% {
    margin-top: -57px;
  }
  /* 3 X tickerv-wrap height px */
  100% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  /* Back to first line */
}

.tickerv-wrap ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  animation-name: tickerv;
  /* Loop through items */
  animation-duration: 7s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, .5, 0);
}

.tickerv-wrap ul:hover {
  /* Pause on mouse hover */
  animation-play-state: paused;
}


/* ITEMS */

.tickerv-wrap ul li {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px/* Same as wrapper height */
}
```

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Vertical News Ticker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="newsTicker.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tickerv-wrap">
    <ul>
      <li>Title 1</li>
      <li>Title 2</li>
      <li>Title 3</li>
      <li>Title 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Method 1: use an SVG.

Method 2: if it doesn't actually matter if you use another element, you can wrap the first half in an element and use transform: rotate on it.

Method 3: use a gradient to cover the first half of the text. Then use a psuedoselector (such as ::after) and absolute position it to match up with the line. Use CSS rotate on the psuedoselector.

Comment: Quick question, I've inspected the site, and noticed the ::after element in it, so I was wondering how pseudoselectors work. Could you explain it briefly or provide some resources?

Comment: More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Comment: Sorry, I meant skew in my comment. I've written an answer explaining 2 of my solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand you correctly. If I understand you correctly, you're trying to add a slanted edge for the ticker. There's some materials here for creating slants:-

- [Shape with a slanted side (responsive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441122/shape-with-a-slanted-side-responsive)
- https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-create-angled-edges-with-sass--cms-31545
- https://css-tricks.com/creating-non-rectangular-headers/

### **Method #1**

Use pseudoselectors + transform (skew).

```css
.tickerv-wrap::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  transform: skew(-30deg);
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.tickerv-wrap::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  z-index: -2;
}

.tickerv-wrap {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 19px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1px;
} 

@keyframes tickerv {
  0%   {margin-top: 0;}
  25%  {margin-top: -19px;}
  50%  {margin-top: -38px;}
  75%  {margin-top: -57px;}
  100% {margin-top: 0;}
}

.tickerv-wrap ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  animation-name: tickerv;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, .5, 0);
}

.tickerv-wrap ul:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.tickerv-wrap ul li {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Vertical News Ticker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="newsTicker.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tickerv-wrap">
      <ul>
        <li>Title 1</li>
        <li>Title 2</li>
        <li>Title 3</li>
        <li>Title 4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Method #2

Use a gradient. Epic.

- (shh...I used https://cssgradient.io <3)

  ```css
  .tickerv-wrap {
    background: rgb(204,204,204);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(204,204,204,1) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 20%, rgba(238,238,238,1) 20%, rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(204,204,204,1) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 20%, rgba(238,238,238,1) 20%, rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(204,204,204,1) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 20%, rgba(238,238,238,1) 20%, rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%);
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 19px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1px;
  } 

  @keyframes tickerv {
    0%   {margin-top: 0;}
    25%  {margin-top: -19px;}
    50%  {margin-top: -38px;}
    75%  {margin-top: -57px;}
    100% {margin-top: 0;}
  }
  .tickerv-wrap ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    animation-name: tickerv;
    animation-duration: 7s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, .5, 0);
  }
  .tickerv-wrap ul:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
  }

  .tickerv-wrap ul li {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <!Doctype HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>Vertical News Ticker</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="newsTicker.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="tickerv-wrap"><ul>
          <li>Title 1</li>
          <li>Title 2</li>
          <li>Title 3</li>
          <li>Title 4</li>
      </ul></div>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

### Method #3

Use an SVG. I just uninstalled Adobe Illustrator so I can't make an SVG right now. I'm sure you could work it out with a Google search.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation! The only problem now is that I have to move the actual ticking object in the ticker to the other side of the slant. It shouldn't be that much of a problem though.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I'm planning to make the left side static, and then have the right side with the changing text.

Comment: Ah. You should've mentioned . I'd recommend either using margins or create a grid/flexbox.

Comment: I think margins will do, but would grids provide a more dynamic solution?

Comment: I'd personally use flexbox, but CSS grids could work here too. Margins will mean that the text on the right will move when the left text is updated. You could also use a relative container and absolute positioning for a more hacky way.

Comment: Yeah, I've resolved to use margins and modified the pseudoselector so that it measures in % and made the margin in % as well.