# Unable to get hover background color work with diagonal cut in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm unable to get the hover background color timing to sync with `:before`. How can I fix this issue?
When you hover over the button, you will notice the transition of the background color is not in sync.

**JSFIDDLE DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/7c25wmuz/**

```css
.btn-primary {
  background-color: #2c9ff5;
  border-color: #2c9ff5;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.btn.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: #45aff6;
  border-color: #45aff6;
}

.btn-donate {
  background-color: #053a86;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
}

.btn-donate:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 30px solid white;
  border-right: 20px solid #053a86;
  width: 0;
}

.btn-donate:hover::before {
  border-right: 20px solid #45aff6;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-donate">Donate</a>
```

Comment: don't use border for this, use clip-path: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30441122/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a background transition to .btn-donate and border transition to .btn-donate:before like so:
(added padding bottom to see things)

```css
body {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.btn-primary {
    background-color: #2c9ff5;
    border-color: #2c9ff5;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.btn.btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: #45aff6;
    border-color: #45aff6;
}
.btn-donate {
    background-color: #053a86;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s  ease background;
}
.btn-donate:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  border-top: 30px solid white;
  border-right: 20px solid #053a86;
  width: 0;
  transition: .3s ease border;
}
.btn-donate:hover::before {
    border-right: 20px solid #45aff6;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-donate">Donate</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Clip path is the solution you need for something like this.

```css
.btn-primary {
    background-color: #2c9ff5;
    border-color: #2c9ff5;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
.btn.btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: #45aff6;
    border-color: #45aff6;
}
.btn-donate {
    background-color: #053a86;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    transition: .5s all ease;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-donate">Donate</a>
```

Comment: missing css `text-decoration: none;`

Comment: that's not at all relevant to what they asked

Comment: it's true, but it's still missing. do you want me to withdraw my comment?

Comment: I have used another solution which is to use transition effect. I will read up on clip functionalities. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you runned into conflict with browser default styles. You can see default styles in your Developer tools (F12) you just need to enable it. Go to developer tools settings and check "Show browser styles".

This issue can be simply fixed by overriding default styles with your own.

```css
body {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.btn {
  transition: unset; /* override, this is all you need */
  
  
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
}

.btn-primary {
    background-color: #2c9ff5;
    border-color: #2c9ff5;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.btn.btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: #45aff6;
    border-color: #45aff6;
}
.btn-donate {
    background-color: #053a86;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
}
.btn-donate:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  border-top: 30px solid white;
  border-right: 20px solid #053a86;
  width: 0;
}
.btn-donate:hover::before {
    border-right: 20px solid #45aff6;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-donate">Donate</a>
```

Comment: What did you change in the code?!

Comment: Yes maybe it's hard to see, there is a comment on one of css lines in the beginning of the file.